# DIV Width Not Expanding To Fit Width Of Child DIVs - IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, width

I have a page with an ASP.NET Gridview on it...this Gridview is located in a child DIV inside a parent DIV.  That Gridview can often go wider than the parent DIV width set.  In IE6 the MAINDIV (Parent DIV) would expand to fit the expanded Gridview contained within the child DIV.  In IE7 the DIV will not expand so it overlaps the DIV and looks bad. I want that MainDiv to dynamically grow with the child DIV width, like it did in IE6.

Please see my code below.   I want the MainDiv to remain ~800px unless it is pushed out further.

Thanks for any ideas on a fix for this. Whenever I try min-width it just blows the parent DIV out to 100% screen size.

```
<body style="width:100%;text-align:center;background-color:#68838B" onload="loadpage();"> 
  <form id="frmMain" runat="server"> 
    <div id="mainDiv" style="position:relative;top:10px;width:800px;height:auto; background-color:white;border:solid 1px #666666"> 
      <div id="contentDiv" style="text-align:left;width:797px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;"> 
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentBody" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code?

Comment: <body style="width:100%;text-align:center;background-color:#68838B" onload="loadpage();">
      <form id="frmMain" runat="server"> 
          <div id="mainDiv" style="position:relative;top:10px;width:800px;height:auto; background-color:white;border:solid 1px #666666">        
                      <div id="contentDiv" style="text-align:left;width:797px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;">
                  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentBody" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                  </div> 
          </div>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: whats the easiest way to post code here? is there some sort of tag i need to use before and after the code?

Comment: I guess in comments you cannot format text.

Comment: edit your original question and paste the code there. indent each line by four spaces

Answer (score 1):

You told it to have a `width:800px` so that's what it has. IE6 incorrectly treated `width` as `min-width`. Move your IE6 styles into a seperate stylesheet and use conditional comments to override `min-width` (which IE6 doesn't support anyway) with `width`.